# Get Notified of Errors in Windows Event Log

Tags: windows-7, windows, powershell, logging, event-log

I wrote a powershell script to make a database dump that I plan on having run nightly with Windows Task Scheduler. It outputs to a log file so I can make sure everything is working, but I want to be informed when something goes wrong without having to check the log manually. My idea was to create a Windows event log for this and other custom scripts and have them all record errors in it. I would like to be notified somehow when an error occurs in this log, such as by sending me an email. Is there a way to do this? I am running Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot. You can define where the logs go, what the error code is, etc. Make it your own. If you want to use gmail to send the message, there's a tutorial I saw a while back. I'm sure you can find it.

```
Try
{
Database dump commands
}
Catch
{
    Write-EVentLog -LogName Application -Source "Baller Script" -EntryType Error -EventID 42 -Message "There has been a failure..."
    Send-MailMessage -From ExpensesBot@MyCompany.Com -To bro@baller.com -Subject "DBDump is broke as hell! (Event ID: 42)" -SmtpServer exch@baller.com
    Break
}
```